# Server stopped working after update to php 5.5.0

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running nginx on ubuntu server 12.04 and I just updated to the most recent php package as follows http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/#.Uzsho1RdURg.

In the final part of the installation I was asked if I wanted to substitute the ***conf*** file since the one on the server was different from the original and I agreed on that. Unfortunately I can't find the conf file in the server so I'd like to know where I can check it because the problem must be within it.

I've tried to ***service php5-fpm restart*** with nginx but it failed and returned the following message

> Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=8013 comm="stop php5-fpm ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Whenever I load the server I get a **502** ***bad gateway***. How can I check what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade packages and the config file differs from the existing one and you decide to replace the config, the old one is saved to a file with `.dpkg-old` extension. If you do not replace the config, the new config from the package is saved with `.dpkg-dist` extension.

So, you can search for your old config file with

```
find /etc -name '*.dpkg*'
```

command, and then you can see what has changed.

In general, you should check the differences between your current and distribution config files with the `diff` option in DPKG during upgrades. That way you can make an informed decision whether to upgrade the config file or not.